# How to use a lambda expression to pass a method as a parameter when calling another method?

Tags: java, parameters, lambda, java-8

Say I have two methods `void chargeToIndividual(int amount, int account)` and `void chargeToCompany(int amount, int account)`. Say I have another method called `void processSale(String item, Customer c)`. What can I do so I can pass either `chargeToIndividual` or `chargeToCompany` as an argument to `processSale` and how would I call it?

For example I want to be able to do

```
if(isIndividual(someCustomer))
{
  processSale(anItem, someCustomer, chargeToIndividual)
}
else if(isCompany(someCustomer))
{
  processSale(anItem, someCustomer, chargeToCustomer)
}
```

and inside `processSale()` how would I actually call `chargeToIndividual` or `chargeToCustomer()`?

Comment: +1 cuz someone had guts to post up this question

Comment: you don't. you pass the company/customer as parameter and let OO choose the right signature for the method (overloading)

Comment: @KickButtowski thanks, I've been searching a round for a while and people half mention it and allude to it but there appears to be no solid explanation with working code (case in point, look at alfasin's poorly written comment above that doesn't make proper sense).

Comment: @alfasin in fairness, the interface is not the same, so clearly it's not part of a polymorphic chain. Otherwise I'd agree 100%. If you have control of both classes, you should set up a proper inheritance tree (or at least implement a consistent interface) so that you can use polymorphism to resolve this problem for you. Or you can overload ``processSale`` to take either an ``Individual`` or a ``Company``, if those are different child classes of ``Customer``.

Comment: Couldn't you use the BiConsuemr interface? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html

Answer (score 2):

You have two functions:

```
void chargeToIndividual(int amount, int account);
void chargeToCompany(int amount, int account);
```

What they have in common is that they both take two `int` parameters and return `void`. There's no functional interface in `java.util.function` that matches this shape. But it's easy to define our own:

```
interface IntIntConsumer {
    void accept(int amount, int account);
}
```

You'd rewrite the calling code as follows:

```
if (isIndividual(someCustomer)) {
    processSale(anItem, someCustomer, MyClass::chargeToIndividual);
} else if (isCompany(someCustomer)) {
    processSale(anItem, someCustomer, MyClass::chargeToCompany);
} else { ... }
```

Or if `chargeToIndividual` and `chargeToCustomer` are instance methods, possibly use `this::chargeToIndividual` and `this::chargeToCustomer`. An alternate formulation would be to store the charging function in a local variable. Then you'll have only one call to `processSale`:

```
IntIntConsumer chargeFunc;

if (isIndividual(someCustomer)) {
    chargeFunc = this::chargeToIndividual;
} else if (isCompany(someCustomer)) {
    chargeFunc = this::chargeToCompany;
} else { ... }

processSale(anItem, someCustomer, chargeFunc);
```

Now in `processSale` the call to the charging function would look like this:

```
void processSale(Item item, Customer customer, IntIntConsumer func) {
    ...
    func.accept(item.getAmount(), customer.getAccount());
    ...
}
```

Of course I've made some assumptions about where to get the `amount` and `account` arguments, but I think you can get the idea.

Comment: Regaurding the two options you propose, does it basically boil down to the argument of when to pass a parameter vs when to set a member field ("store the charging function in a local variable")? Is there a difference in terms of speed?

Comment: @Celeritas Not a member field but a local variable. I doubt there is a speed difference. It's more a matter of style and code factoring. In the first approach there are two calls to `processSale`; some people might find that repetitious. If you extract the differences between this calls into a local variable, it reduces the code to a single call to `processSale`, but to figure out what it's doing, you have to trace through the assignments to the local variable. I think the circumstances will dictate which is preferable.

Comment: It seems like when using lambda expressions to implement interfaces, you no longer need the keyword implements, for example in your example you never have `implements IntIntConsumer`.

Comment: @Celeritas Right, the lambda is automatically converted into an instance of the *target type* which must be a functional interface. As such the `implements IntIntConsumer` or whatever is implicit and needn't be declared. However on the receiving side, if you test the parameter value with `instanceof IntIntConsumer` the result will be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is about using lambdas:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class PlayWithLambdas {

    public void testIsCustomer(Consumer<Chargeable> f) {
        Chargeable customer = new Customer();
        Chargeable company = new Company();
        f.accept(customer); // prints "true"
        f.accept(company);  // prints "false"
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PlayWithLambdas p = new PlayWithLambdas();
        p.testIsCustomer(chargeable -> {
            System.out.println(chargeable.getType().equals(ChargeableType.CUSTOMER));
        });
    }    
}

interface Chargeable {
    public ChargeableType getType();
}

class Customer implements Chargeable {
    @Override
    public ChargeableType getType() {
        return ChargeableType.CUSTOMER;
    }
}

class Company  implements Chargeable {
    @Override    
    public ChargeableType getType() {
        return ChargeableType.COMPANY;
    }
}

enum ChargeableType {
    CUSTOMER, COMPANY;
}
```

I hope that this poor writer that doesn't make any sense was able to help you :)

Comment: Should the implementation of `getType()` use `@override` annotation?

Comment: I ask because Netbeans doesn't suggest it with lambda expressions where it does in other cases. I guess Netbeans just hasn't caught up with Java 8 yet.

Comment: @Celeritas good catch! you might want to [submit a bug](https://netbeans.org/bugs.html)